# How do I resolve a Visual Studio MPF 15.0 Dependency Alert so that I may install Zebble for Xamarin extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin-zebble, zebble

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I am trying to install the Zebble for Xamarin extension via the Tools > Extensions and Updates dialog box. When I click download I get the following Dependency Alert:

> The following reference must be present before installation can continue: Visual Studio MPF 15.0

A tip at the bottom advises:

> To obtain a reference, click its name, look for it on the Online, or
>   search for it on the Internet. Restart Visual Studio after installing
>   the references above to use this extension.

I've tried:

- Clicking the name but it appears to be unclickable
- Searching for it on the Internet and have only come across Visual Studio 2017 RC issues linking to different githubs

Comment: MPF 15.0 is a Visual Studio 2017 thing so you may be installing the wrong version of your thing. Or not but this is something to be mindful of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency to MPF is now removed from the latest version of Zebble extension (as of 3.96).

You should install the latest Zebble extension. You can do it directly from  Visual Studio, or from this URL: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Paymon.ZebbleforXamarin