# VSIX - Reference are missing - Visual Studio MPF 15.0 - Zebble Framework for Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, vsix, zebble

I have a issue with the installation of ZebbleVSIX.vsix for Visual Studio.

[MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Paymon.ZebbleforXamarin)

I want to try the Framework for Xamarin but I can't install it.

> This Extension cannot be installed bescause the following reference are missing: - Visual Studio MPF 15.0

I see this post on SOF => [How do I resolve a Visual Studio MPF 15.0 Dependency Alert so that I may install Zebble for Xamarin extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212498/how-do-i-resolve-a-visual-studio-mpf-15-0-dependency-alert-so-that-i-may-install)

I try to install the last version, this should not appear as a problem.

I found others solutions solutions => [Control Extension: exception during installation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/189e5a74-3fe2-4f62-bc97-adbfdc47716b/control-extension-exception-during-installation?forum=vsx)

If i try to modify something in the .vsix installation failed.

[VSIX Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEUMm.png)

Where can I found the VSIX manifest editor in Visual Studio to change the line with Visual Studio MPF 15.0 ?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to install the package with the Nuget command line => https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zebble/ => PM > Install-Package Zebble -Version 4.2.369

Comment: It is the reference, but I can't download the Zebble Template. I'm trying to install the Template like this exemple => http://zebble.net/docs/preparing-visual-studio-for-installing-zebble